# Pointer Statement in Scapegoat Tree

Tags: c++

```
SGTNode **a = new SGTNode* [ns];
```

Can anyone please help me with this statement in Scape Goat Tree implementation in C++.
Link to C++ program : https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-scapegoat-tree/

Comment: *Can anyone please help me with this statement* -- `SGTNode **a = new SGTNode [ns];` --What is there that is not understandable in that statement?  I don't know how you are approaching learning C++, but you can't learn such a complex language by picking out lines of code from some implementation of a data structure.  That line of code is perfectly understandable to anyone who has gone through the proper preparation of learning C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That statement allocates an array of `ns` pointers-to-SGTNode (aka `SGTNode *`) on the heap.

After the statement completes, the local variable `a` is pointing to the first pointer-to-SGTNode in the array, which is why the type of `a` is `SGTNode **` (i.e. `a` is a pointer-to-a-(pointer-to-SGTNode))